# Split a 3D numpy array to get all series with consecutive values that meet a condition

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I want to get all the sequences of number meeting a condition in a 3D array along axis 0. I am trying to vectorize everything if possible to avoid wildly inefficient loops.

The following code works, it takes array a defined, with shape (6, 2, 3) for example. It applies a mask on it, defined by array b (same dimensions).

Then, I slice my 3D array along axis 0, so that I have 2*3 1D slices, and thus obtain 6 1D array of shape (6,). In order to do that, I use a loop, which is obviously going to be an efficiency problem with larger arrays.

I then split my array according to the mask obtained, and select (simple print for now) the series with at least 3 consecutive values meeting the conditions given by the b array.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[0.57337127, 0.7626088, 0.26965987],
               [0.66987041, 0.2914202, 0.62678441]],
              [[0.97442524, 0.61656519, 0.10544983],
               [0.05780219, 0.00381356, 0.57118615]],
              [[0.47069657, 0.36802822, 0.67483419],
               [0.32773146, 0.99773064, 0.56042508]],
              [[0.70984651, 0.25093198, 0.71911127],
               [0.05182876, 0.9463291, 0.7222756]],
              [[0.56736192, 0.62692889, 0.33814278],
               [0.72362855, 0.12885637, 0.44096788]],
              [[0.12706838, 0.90640269, 0.5126569],
               [0.62920448, 0.24502599, 0.26754067]]])

b = np.array([[[0.4, 0.4, 0.4],
               [0.4, 0.4, 0.4]],
              [[0.4, 0.4, 0.4],
               [0.4, 0.4, 0.4]],
              [[0.4, 0.4, 0.4],
               [0.4, 0.4, 0.4]],
              [[0.4, 0.4, 0.4],
               [0.4, 0.4, 0.4]],
              [[0.4, 0.4, 0.4],
               [0.4, 0.4, 0.4]],
              [[0.4, 0.4, 0.4],
               [0.4, 0.4, 0.4]]])

# these two loops i and j are very inefficient 
for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    for j in range(a.shape[2]):
        print(i, j)
        aij = a[:, i, j]
        bij = b[:, i, j]
        mask = aij <= bij
        split_indices = np.where(mask)[0]
        for subarray in np.split(aij, split_indices + 1):
            if len(subarray) > 3:
                print(subarray[:-1])
```

Now, this works. **However**, my actual data (arrays a and b) is of shape ~(500, 800, 1500), which means that the loop is becoming problematic (pretty expensive).

Can you think of a way to vectorize it more? I've tried to get a 3D mask and split 3D-wise, but that would give unequal size of split along axis 1 and 2 which is an issue (and the reason why np.split takes only a 0 or 1-D indices list.

Comment: is the array b always just an array of the same constant in each position or is that for the sake of the example? One thought that comes to mind is subtracting the two slices and then using np.where to set entries with negative values to zero and then applying that as a mask. I am not sure how to implement that though.

Comment: The b is given as a constant here for "ease of reading" but is going to be variable eventually. I can get a 3D mask pretty easily, but I can't see how to use that 3D mask to find consecutive "True" series (of variable lengths) over the axis. That is, the np.split function needs a 0 or 1-D indices array by definition, and I can't think of a way to give it (or a similar vectorized function) a 3D mask to get all the series at once without the need for the i,j slicing

Comment: Though your comment made me think that indeed, putting the slicing in the loop itself is not very efficient, and I can just move that outside of the loop to get the 3D mask and slice the mask itself in the loop. Not a groundbreaking gain but still a tiny bit better at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over axis `(1,2)`, you can loop through axis `0` to iteratively check whether the mask holds for consecutive elements. Depending on what exactly you want to achieve in the end, it will take at most `n` iterations (where `n` is the longest sequence you have).

For instance, if you simply want to identify the starting elements of any valid sequence of at least 3 consecutive elements along `axis=0` that satisfy `mask`, you would do:

```
mask = a > b
runs = np.zeros_like(mask, dtype=bool)
runs[:-2] = mask[:-2] & mask[1:-1] & mask[2:]
```

In your example, this yields:

```
>>> runs
array([[[ True, False, False],
    [False, False,  True]],
   [[ True, False, False],
    [False, False,  True]],
   [[ True, False, False],
    [False, False,  True]],
   [[False, False, False],
    [False, False, False]],
   [[False, False, False],
    [False, False, False]],
   [[False, False, False],
    [False, False, False]]])
```

Here, `runs` evaluates to `True` for all starting elements of a valid sequence of at least length 3. As I am not sure what you want to do once you identified them, I am leaving it at this. But hopefully it's clear how to generalize from here on for whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: This is a very smart approach. I'm playing with this principle to adapt to my needs (my non-optimized solution would take literally months to run, so I'm pretty motivated).